# why doesn't gevent come with its own arsenal of functions, instead of monkey patching existing ones?

Tags: python, gevent, monkeypatching

The monkey-patching needed to use gevent is prone to mistakes, doesn't work well with REPL etc'.

My question is - wouldn't it be easier to just ship a custom version of `requests` within gevent, with the same API as the standard library, and allow the programmer to use it explicitly whenever they choose to?

(of course this assumes that the raw requests are not done by an internal lib, but this is often the case)

Does such a solution already exist?

Comment: My guess is that by monkey patching the enable software that is gevent agnostic to work with gevent, but only developers can answer this for sure

Comment: Why a certain design decision has been made in a software should be discussed with the people who made the decision.

Comment: @KlausD. this isn't a "discussion", there was a reason (hopefully an interesting one) why they decided it which might be public knowledge and I want to know it, while asking if a solution exists that offers a different path.

Comment: @Uri, but in the big picture you are not using one module with gevent, often dozens of modules are used in projects, so _someone_ would need to refactor all of them ?!

Comment: Right, so I'd imagine the choice should be left to the user whether they want it to work implicitly or explicitly.